# Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore$KeySet. when deploying Grails 2.5 on Tomcat 7.0.42 App

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I'm finding the following problem when deploying an application grails 2.5.0 on tomcat 7.0.42.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore$KeySet. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.CompoundStore.keySet(CompoundStore.java:216)
        at net.sf.ehcache.store.compound.factories.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:670)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Running the application via run-app grails application works normally! I realized that there is a difference between versions of Tomcat, the embedded version is in build ": tomcat: 7.0.54" and the environment is with Apache Tomcat / 7.0.42

The closest I found the problem in the [link](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/searchable-plugin-issue-td4628845.html)  suggested a 'downgrade' version, which is not a viable solution at the moment! which may be the cause of this problem? A bug in the version of tomcat or application?

Comment: Upgrade the running tomcat?  You are deployed to an older tomcat than what's in the build configuration so surely you should upgrade tomcat rather than downgrade build configuration?